# Prove that area of ellipse $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1$ is equal to $\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}$

Tags: integration, conic-sections

Question:

If $B^2-4AC \lt 0$, the equation
$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1$$

represents an ellipse. Prove that the area of the ellipse is
$\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}$.

I know that, if $2a$ and $2b$ are the major and minor axis of the ellipse respectively, its area is $\pi ab$.

I honestly have no idea how to go about this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Solve the equation for $y$ in terms of $x$.  Integrate the upper value minus the lower value, over the interval where the solutions are real.

Comment: How do i get rid of the shared value $Bxy$ ??

Comment: Solve for y in terms of $x$ ... quadratic formula ...
$$
Cy^2 + (Bx)y + (Ax^2-1) = 0
\\
y = \frac{-Bx\pm\sqrt{4C-(4AC-B^2)x^2}}{2C}
$$

Comment: Ohhh okay thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: Do you know about eigenvalues of a matrix?

Comment: @amd no, I don't. weirdly enough It is mentioned once in our book but I don't ever remember us having explained it in previous years. The question was solved using the tip GEdgar gave me though, which is just using the quadratic formula and integrals, so luckily looks like I didn't need to know about eigenvalues of a matrix after all!

Comment: For future questions, please provide more background information. When there are multiple ways to attack a problem, like here, it’s hard to give you an answer you’ll understand without knowing what you’ve got to work with.

Comment: @amd okay, I'll try to do that

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** For a linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2$ given by
$$\pmatrix{u\\v} = \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} \pmatrix{x\\y} ,$$
the areas of a (nice) region $E \subset \Bbb R^2$ (e.g., our ellipse) and its image $T(E) \subset \Bbb R^2$ are related by
$$\textrm{area}(T(E)) = |{\det T}| \,\textrm{area}(E) .$$
On the other hand, we know that there is a linear transformation $T$ that maps our ellipse to the unit ball, and so for such a transformation rearranging the previous equation gives
$$\textrm{area}(E) = \frac{\textrm{area}(T(E))}{|{\det T}|} = \frac{\pi}{|{\det T}|} .$$
So, we need only write $|{\det T}|$ in terms of $A, B, C$, and in particular show that $$|{\det T}| = |a d - b c| = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4 A C - B^2} .$$

> **Additional hint** Substituting using the transformation formula for $T$ gives that in $xy$-coordinates the unit circle is $$(a^2 + c^2) x^2 + 2(ab + cd) x y + (b^2 + d^2) y^2 .$$ Thus, the desired transformation satisfies $$A = a^2 + c^2, \quad B = 2 (a b + c d), \quad C = b^2 + d^2.$$

Comment: Sorry, I dont really understand this. I dont think I have studied the materials necessary to understand it. But thanks anyways, maybe someone else will instead :)

Comment: What course are you taking? If it's the integral symbols (calculus) that you find daunting, they're not really necessary: It's enough to know that, given a linear transformation $T$, the areas of the regions $E$ and $T(E)$ are related by $\textrm{area}(T(E)) = |{\det T}| \textrm{area}(E)$. (In fact, perhaps I'll edit the answer to reflect this.) By design, in our case $T(E)$ is a unit circle, so $\textrm{T(E)} = \pi$, which is enough to give the second display equation.

Comment: I don't have issues with integral calculus , rather I've never really taken Linear transformation and how they relate to areas ( atleast I don't think I've taken linear transformation) and matrices so I dont know how to use those. I'm a senior high-school student

Comment: What course is this from them? Do you have a particular related results available?

Comment: i dont have any related results, and Where I come from ( a region in the middle east) we don't have  "courses" per say, rather we just study the book as is, so I doubt I can find any info on that. edit : actually, I just checked last year's book and it did have matrices , but looks like we just skipped the subject like many of the other ones due to alot of time restraints (schools started pretty late last year due to many issues)

Comment: Another way to find $\det(T)$ in terms of the original equation’s coefficients is to use $\det(T^{-T}CT^{-1})=1$, where $C$ is the original conic’s matrix.

Answer (score 1):

In polar coordinates, the ellipse is given by
$$r^2 (\theta)= \frac1{A\cos^2\theta +B\cos\theta\sin\theta +C\sin^2\theta}$$

Denote $\Delta = \sqrt{(A-C)^2+B^2}$ and integrate its area as follows

\begin{align}
A=\frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} r^2(\theta)\> d\theta
&= \frac12 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{A\cos^2\theta +B\cos\theta\sin\theta +C\sin^2\theta}\> d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(A+C)+(A-C)\cos 2\theta +B\sin2\theta}\> d\theta\\
 &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(A+C)+\Delta\cos 2\theta }\>d\theta\\
&= 4\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d(\tan\theta)}{(A+C+\Delta)+(A+C-\Delta)\tan^2\theta }\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{(A+C)^2 - \Delta^2}}
=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}\\
\end{align}