# Show that the equation $(a^2+1)x^2 + 2(a+b) xy + (b^2+1)y^2 =c$ represents an ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

> Show that the equation:
>
> $$(a^2+1)x^2 + 2(a+b) xy + (b^2+1)y^2 =c$$
>
> in which $c>0$ represents an ellipse of area $\dfrac{\pi c}{ab-1}$.

I attempt to show $(a^2+1)(b^2+1)-(a+b)^2>0$ which means $\Delta<0$.But how could I do this without knowing any information of $a$ and $b$?

Please anyone help me to show that the equation represents an ellipse of area $\dfrac{\pi c}{ab-1}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The expression for area is undefined when $ab=1$, so there must be some other conditions on $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Is there any way to show that area $\dfrac{\pi c}{ab-1}$ without knowing the conditions on a and b @amd

Comment: There’s a perhaps no so well known formula for the area of an arbitrary rotated ellipse $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2=1$. The area is $2\pi/\sqrt{4AC-B^2}$. You can find the sketch of a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2499695/265466). Otherwise, you might compute the eigenvalues of the associated matrix. This involves solving a quadratic equation. Simple, but tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quicker way is to re-arrange the conic:

\begin{align}
  c &= (ax+y)^2+(x+by)^2 \\
  c &= u^2+v^2 \\
  u &= ax+y \\
  v &= x+by \\
  du \, dv &=
  \frac{\partial (u,v)}{\partial (x,y)} \, dx \, dy \\
  \pi c &= A
  \begin{Vmatrix}
    a & 1 \\
    1 & b
  \end{Vmatrix} \\
  A &= \frac{\pi c}{|ab-1|}
\end{align}

> - $u$ and $v$ are two skew axes re-scaled respectively by $\sqrt{a^2+1}$ and $\sqrt{b^2+1}$ and made by an angle of $\theta=\sin^{-1} \dfrac{|ab-1|}{\sqrt{(a^2+1)(b^2+1)}}$.
> - For $ab=1$, the conic degenerates into two parallel lines.

Answer (score 1):

Very good approach, here is a proof that for almost all $a,b$ the innequality is true;$$(a^2+1)(b^2+1)-(a+b)^2=a^2b^2+1-2ab=(ab-1)^2\geq0$$The only way that they are equal, is if $ab=1\to a=\frac1b$. In this case it's not representing a elipse.

Comment: and what about the area. @David

Comment: @mdemon That comes out of the formula for the general elipse, $S=\frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{4AC-B^2}}$ since we have shown that $4AC-B^2=(2(ab-1))^2$